# Would using a cooler plug help or even prevent this level of exhaust valve damage

Tags: overheating, valve

As I posted in a related question:
[Help me diagnose the cause of this intake valve burn](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/43589/help-me-diagnose-the-cause-of-this-intake-valve-burn)

[image: https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/43589/help-me-diagnose-the-cause-of-this-intake-valve-burn]

Here is depicted an instance of its EXHAUST (not intake) valve burn, the key note being there was a head deck to increase compression ratio from 9 to 10.

I am curious of the feasibility that using a cooler plug has a genuine chance to draw enough heat in order to prevent this level of damage.

Note this damage accumulated after roughly 1000 miles of primarily red line driving on a single cylinder 167fmm 229cc engine...

Comment: What material is the valve made of?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From what I understand of cool/hot spark plugs, the idea is not that they are absorbing a significant amount of heat that would otherwise be burning your valves.  Cooler plugs keep the tip of the plug cooler which lessens the chance of detonation, particularily in racing applications (which I am assuming this is, "primarily red line driving").  From reading your other question, it sounds like it wasn't detonating.

So no, your spark plug isn't going to absorb enough heat to prevent a valve from burning.